# R create lag variable in unbalance time series dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, lag

I want to create a lag variable in my dataframe.

I have a list of time `c("20110127", "20110128", "20110129", "20110130", "20110131", "20110201", "20110202")`.

My dataframe look like:

| ID | TIME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20110127 | 3.23 |
| 1 | 20110128 | 4.57 |
| 1 | 20110130 | 3.22 |
| 1 | 20110131 | 4.33 |
| 1 | 20110202 | 5.23 |
| 2 | 20110127 | 0.86 |
| 2 | 20110128 | 7.55 |
| 2 | 20110129 | 1.24 |
| 2 | 20110201 | 3.69 |

The year in the table is not consecutive. And I want to group_by ID then create a one-day lag variable. Which look like this:

| ID | TIME | VALUE | LAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20110127 | 3.23 | NA |
| 1 | 20110128 | 4.57 | 3.23 |
| 1 | 20110130 | 3.22 | NA |
| 1 | 20110131 | 4.33 | 3.22 |
| 1 | 20110201 | 1.22 | 4.33 |
| 1 | 20110202 | 5.23 | 1.22 |
| 2 | 20110127 | 0.86 | NA |
| 2 | 20110128 | 7.55 | 0.86 |
| 2 | 20110129 | 1.24 | 7.55 |
| 2 | 20110201 | 3.69 | NA |

I tried

```
alltime = c("20110127", "20110128", "20110129", "20110130", "20110131", "20110201", "20110202")

last_day = data %>%
    arrange(ID, TIME) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(lagtime = alltime[which(alltime == TIME)+1], lagoutput = value ,value = NULL)
data %>%
    left_join(last_day)
```

But it seems like the mutate function wouldn't work here. Maybe the problem is `alltime[which(alltime == TIME)+1]` and I cannot create a lag.

Appreciate any comment.

Comment: In my answer I use your first data frame. In your second one, you appear to have an extra row (ID = 1, TIME = "20110201", VALUE = 1.22).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an `ifelse` statement. So, if the rows are 1 day apart (here I convert to a time format using `lubridate`), then return `lag` `value` and if not return `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  arrange(ID, TIME) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(LAG = ifelse(ymd(TIME) - lag(ymd(TIME)) == 1, lag(VALUE), NA))
```

**Output**

```
      ID     TIME VALUE   LAG
   <int>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 20110127  3.23 NA   
 2     1 20110128  4.57  3.23
 3     1 20110130  3.22 NA   
 4     1 20110131  4.33  3.22
 5     1 20110201  1.22  4.33
 6     1 20110202  5.23  1.22
 7     2 20110127  0.86 NA   
 8     2 20110128  7.55  0.86
 9     2 20110129  1.24  7.55
10     2 20110201  3.69 NA
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    TIME = c(20110127L, 20110128L, 20110130L, 20110131L, 20110201L, 
    20110202L, 20110127L, 20110128L, 20110129L, 20110201L), VALUE = c(3.23, 
    4.57, 3.22, 4.33, 1.22, 5.23, 0.86, 7.55, 1.24, 3.69)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff()` and `lubridate::ymd()` to make a temporary column that indicates if there are gaps in the dates; then leverage that gap to get conditional lag of `VALUE`

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(g = c(0,diff(lubridate::ymd(TIME))),
         LAG = if_else(g==1,lag(VALUE),as.double(NA))) %>% 
  select(-g)
```

Output:

```
     ID     TIME VALUE   LAG
  <int>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 20110127  3.23 NA   
2     1 20110128  4.57  3.23
3     1 20110130  3.22 NA   
4     1 20110131  4.33  3.22
5     1 20110202  5.23 NA   
6     2 20110127  0.86 NA   
7     2 20110128  7.55  0.86
8     2 20110129  1.24  7.55
9     2 20110201  3.69 NA
```